# If $xy=z^2+1$ for natural $x$, $y$, $z$, prove that $x=a^2+b^2$, $y=c^2+d^2$, $z=ac+bd$ for some integers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, complex-numbers, contest-math, problem-solving

A contest-math number theory problem

> If $x,y,z \in \mathbb{N}$ and $xy=z^2+1$, prove that there exist integers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ such that $x=a^2+b^2$, $y=c^2+d^2$, $z=ac+bd$.

---

After working for 20 hours, I learned that there is a solution using complex numbers.  But I have no idea about the solution.
I don't know what will come out of this.

$$xy=(z-i)(z+i)$$

I guess if I could prove that $x = (a-bi)(a+bi)$ and that $y=(c-di)(c+di)$ then maybe I would get a result.

But I don't know how to relate this to the fact that $a, b, c, d$ are integers.

> **Question 1: (Main)**
>
> Can we find a solution using pure number theory without using a complex numbers?
>
> **Question 2:**
>
> How can a solution be made using complex numbers?

I would love to get a detailed answer.  Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Try to understand which are the numbers that are sums of square, try to understand that the product of numbers that are sum of squares is again a sum of squares. About the point 2, those are not simply complex numbers.. Those are Gauss integers, are a set of numbers like the integers, but his irriducible elements are related with the integer primes that are sums of square.

Answer (score 1):

The method below does not require knowing all the primes that can be expressed as the sum of two squares.

We have determinant $1$ in
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x & z \\
z & y
\end{array}
\right)
$$
As the entries and trace are positive, it is positive definite.
Gauss reduction is the finite process of multiplying successively in the form $A \mapsto P^T A P,$ with the choice of
$$
P =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & n \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
or
$$
P =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
until the final output is the identity matrix. This comes from the inequalities of Gauss reduction. So $I = P_j^T A P_j $ for an integer matrix $P_j$ of determinant $1.$   By taking $Q = P_j^{-1}$ we get
$$ A = Q^T Q  $$

$$
Q =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & c \\
b & d
\end{array}
\right)
$$

NOTE: Gauss reduced means $\langle r,2s,t \rangle$
with $1 \leq r \leq t,$ then $-r < 2s \leq r,$ in the matrix below. A little fiddling with inequalities is needed.

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
r & s \\
s & t
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Does your answer mean that there is no solution at the Middleschool level (elementary number theory, and algebra precalculus)?

Comment: @Elementary probably not. The hint needs Gauss integers, unique factorization. My version is about as low-budget as it gets. You do not actually need matrices, it just appears cleaner. Let's see, I recommend Dickson (1929) Introduction to the Theory of Numbers, he does all this and rarely uses matrices.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Notice that every odd prime factor $p$ dividing $z^2+1$ satisfies $p\equiv 1\bmod 4$, since it is the only way that $-1$ is a quadratic residue (we will treat the case $2\mid z^2+1$ at the end). Besides, Fermat's theorem establishes that for every $p\equiv 1\bmod 4$ there exist integers $r,s$ such that $p=r^2+s^2$ (this can be proven, e.g., with Thue's Lemma). Thus, both $x,y$ are a product of odd numbers (and possibly powers of these odd numbers).

Yet, we also have from Brahmagupta's Identity that $$(r^2 + s^2)(t^2 + u^2) = (rt + su)^2 + (ru - st)^2 $$ You can, hence, take two odd primes - say $p_1$ and $p_2$ - , and write them as a sum of squares: $p_1\cdot p_2=(r^2+s^2)(t^2+u^2)=(rt+su)^2+(ru-st)^2$. Use this identity repeatedly. Can you finish?

For the case $2\mid z^2+1$, notice that $2=1^2+1^2$.

Now, we just need to prove that these $a,b,c,d$ satisfy $ad - bc=\pm1$. This looks harder using elementary techniques; I might try it later...

Comment: One potential issue is that there could be multiple ways to express $x,y$ in that form, which do not lead to $z = ac+bd$ (iff $ad-bc = \pm1$).

Comment: That’s what I was thinking of @Calvin Lin... I imagine that some argument using infinite descendent might work, but one will then have to construct a smaller solution, and this does not look that simple